# My stack is not returning the right value which is affecting the computation

Tags: assembly

I am currently writing an assembly program to calculate the factorial of a number recursively. Having gone through the debugger, I have seen what's happening. So e.g 3 factorial.

```
public  f              ; make sure function name is exported
f:
  push    ebp          ; push frame pointer
  mov     ebp, esp     ; update ebp
  push    edi
  mov     ecx, [ebp+8] ; gettting my parameter at p0
  mov     edi, ecx     ; making a copy
  cmp     edi, 1       ; check if n is greater than 0
  jle     finished
  dec     ecx          ; subtrack 1 frm parameter
  push    ecx          ; passing new value of n to parameter p0
  mov     eax, 0
  call    f
  mul     edi          ; multiplying n * n-1
  jmp     finished2

finished:   
  mov    eax, 1
finished2:  
  pop    edi
  mov    esp, ebp
  pop    ebp
  ret
```

So lets say I have 3 as my input, I should have something like

```
eax * 3(ecx)
eax * 2(ecx)
```

but I have noticed that on the way back after hitting the base case.. The value 2 is put in the right place but the value 3 never goes into the right place.

Comment: Someone has to clean up the stack after calling `f` - either the callee ([`RET n`](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/ret.htm)) or the caller (`ADD esp, n`), where `n` is equal to the number of bytes you're putting into the stack as function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

when using debugger , i would use info reg (under gdb) to make sure if the registers are having the correct value

```
_start:
pushl $4, 
popl %ebx

call f

f:
        movl %esp,%ebp
        movl 8(%ebp), %eax 
        cmpl $1, %eax  
        je finish
        decl %eax      
        pushl %eax    
        call factorial  
        popl %ebx                   
        incl %ebx 
        imul %ebx, %eax
finish:
movl   %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```